# Can I push Google API app to "production" if it's a desktop app with no website, for just 4 internal users, without a fee?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

BACKGROUND: I have a small business with 4 employees.  We schedule services with clients using Google Calendar.  In a past life I was a professional programmer, but today I just dabble... I'm using VB.NET to make a desktop app which interacts with Google Calendar using its API.  Beyond scheduling it adds a few few other features which help our scheduling, tying into our customer database.  My app will never have more than 4 users and it will never have a website.

THE PROBLEM: I have to admit it's not a big problem, but I have to refresh the token every 7 days.  If I could push my app to "production" the tokens would last longer of course.  Generally, Google has to verify your app, and the process may be impossible without visiting the Googleplex in person because it's a desktop app.  (They ask for the app's website, which it doesn't have.)

BUT... It appears that I might (or might not) be able to push my app to production if I change my user type to Internal, and if so verification may not necessary.  Sounds good but the problem is I can't switch the user type to Internal unless I become a Google Workspace user, for $6 per month per user... and that's just not worth $24 per month to eliminate the need to refresh tokens once a week.  And they may still expect an unnecessary website.

TLDR: Isn't there some way to get longer-lasting API tokens for a simple 4-user desktop-based implementation of their API without paying $6 a month per user?

[Edit for Linda]
Your answer seems great, but I'm still hesitant due to the images pasted below.  Upon clicking it asked if I was sure with the popup shown below, then I confirmed and it sure implies that I need to be ready to take steps I won't be able to take.  It cites my use of "sensitive scopes".  You sure this is going to work out?

[image: Here's the 'are you sure' message.]

[image: Here's the result.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting your app in production to get a long lived refresh token is not the same as verification of an application.

You do not need to be verified to set your app in production and get a long lived refresh token [How to fix Invalid grant Token has expired or revoked #googleoauth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Szy-tL2g0Q)

Solution just click the button its free.

Comment: Wow, thanks!  (And you're the one in the video, nice!)

Comment: Um, but... See my edits in the original post.  (I can't paste images here.)

Comment: hit confirm ignore that message.  I have asked the team to fix it they dont agree with me about the confusion it  causes.